# How to make Outlook keep notification in systray until the messages are read?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, notifications

Currently Outlook works like this:

- I get new email
- Outlook shows notification in systray
- after 5-10 seconds notification is removed

How to make it as simple condition:

- unread messages in inbox -- show notification
- no new messages -- no notification

? So until I Outlook mark new messages as read, notification should stay.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The function just isn't there in Outlook.
The only thing you can do is to increase the timeout (somewhere in the settings panels of Outlook, but I don't have Outlook here to check where exactly).

There are 3rd party mail-notification tools that can work with Outlook. (Both as a Outlook add-in or as a separate program that monitors your mailbox independently from Outlook.)
A former co-worker of mine used to use one of those for this particular feature (so there is at least one add-on that can do it), but the name of that program escapes me.

Comment: Thank you. For the record, I am talking about icon with envelope, so technically speaking, it is possible to keep it as long as someone wishes. Outlook devs probably missed the need of longer timeout. I will this question open for a while, maybe someone has another idea.

Answer (score 1):

For the fellow search engine travelers, there is a work around.

You can set the Alert timeout to 50 days, using a registry setting:

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Common\DesktopAlerts
Value name: TimeOn
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value: 4294964295 (Decimal)
```

If this key isn’t available choose Edit-> New-> DWORD Value and name it `TimeOn` (case sensitive!).

On Windows 8 or higher, running Outlook 2013 or higher, Windows instead controls notifications through the action centre. The default notification display time is 5 seconds, but can be made as long as 5 minutes by changing the message duration (in seconds):

```
Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility
Value name: MessageDuration
Value type: REG_DWORD
```

Source : http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/newmailalert.htm

Comment: The best for me is: "Show a Mail Alert with a list of all newly received e-mails' from http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/newmailalert.htm. Thanks.